# how to create a method that uses 2D array in java

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'd like to create a method that counts how many times 
a number is occurred in a 2D array.
using for loop

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you try to solve this yourself already? If so, where did you get stuck exactly? I general, people don't respond too well to "please make this code for me"-requests (which this looks like), but **do** respond well to "I tried this and now I'm stuck/confused, please help"-requests ;-)

Answer (score 1):

2D arrays can be declared like `int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];` If you need 2D array with different number of values in rows, than you have to create each row by yourself:

```
int [][] matrix = new int[10][];
matrix[0] = new int[10];
matrix[1] = new int[20];
//...
```

To iterate over `matrix` you need

```
for (int[] row : matrix) {
    for (int value : row) {
        sum += value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Danis  please see what he actually asks and what you try to answer ?

Comment: For example i want to find which number is greater than any number in 2D arrays and for this, i create a this code :

int [][] movie = {
     {4,6,2,5},
     {7,9,4,8},
     {6,9,3,7}
   };
   
int count =0;
for(int i = 0; i<movie.length;i++)
   for(int j = 0; j<movie[i].length;j++)
   if(rate == movie[i][j]){
    count++;
    
    }

  System.out.println(count); 

 }

Comment: @ÇağrıÇetiner You have asked about counting the occurrences of a number within a 2-D Array. not mentioning any greater or less than context in your question. So my answer is as per your question .

Answer (score 0):

```
   //method to count your number of Occurrences in Your 2-D Array.    
private int getAllOccurence(int [] arr, int yourNumberToSearch){ 
 int count = 0;
for (int[] row : arr) {      //loop will able to get all Rows

    for (int value : row) {      //loop enables you to get each values of each Row.

       // This if Statement will check wheather Your Number exists in array or not
        if(value == yourNumberToSearch) 
              count++; //count increase each times by one If Number exists in a array.
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

> Here You may try this. You will get Your Answer.

Comment: i cant understand that part : for (int[] row : arr) {
    for (int value : row) {

Comment: its a double dimensional array so First loop will get your all rows. And nested loop (for which is inside a for loop) will get you each element of your row.

Comment: @ÇağrıÇetiner Now I am edit my answer and add comment to abbreviate my answer which makes you a little more understandable

Comment: @ÇağrıÇetiner If you get your answer then accept it as a verified. This answer might helpful for others